# set controller attribute in promise before continue

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Hi I have a doubt in how using promises in Ember. Basically I want to setup the attributes of my controller before running what is next the promise, my code:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  min: null,
  max: null,

  isValid: Ember.computed(function(){
    var self = this;

    var result = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      var url = "..."
      Ember.$.getJSON(url).then(function(data){
        if (data[0] === 0){
          self.set('errorMessage', "It is a free book");
          return false;
        } else if (data[0] > 2000){
          self.set('errorMessage', "You are poor, go for next");
          return false;
        } else {
          console.log(data); # line 2 of console result
          self.set('min', data[1]);
          self.set('max', data[2]);
          return true;
        }
      });
    });
  }
  return result;
}),

actions: {
    save: function(){
        if (this.get('isValid')){
            console.log('save action is fired. -- VALID' + '--' + this.get('maxPrice')); # line 1 of console result
        } else {
            console.log('save action is fired. -- INVALID');
        }
    }
}           

});
```

The thing is in the third if statement, the code in save action is running before setting the attributes min and max inside the promise. Result in console:

```
> save action is fired. -- VALID--null
> [9, 1, 20]
```

Any idea how to set the values before the action go ahead?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much point in wrapping the jquery promise with another promise.  Just use the jquery promise, return it, and then since this is an async world, you need to `then` off of that promise.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    min: null,
    max: null,

    checkValid: function(url) {
        var self = this;
        return Ember.$.getJSON(url).then(function(data) {
            if (data[0] === 0) {
                self.set('errorMessage', "It is a free book");
                return false;
            } else if (data[0] > 2000) {
                self.set('errorMessage', "You are poor, go for next");
                return false;
            } else {
                console.log(data);#
                line 2 of console result
                self.set('min', data[1]);
                self.set('max', data[2]);
                return true;
            }
        });
    },

    actions: {
        save: function() {
            var self = this;
            var url = ...;
            this.checkValid(url).then(function(result) {
                if (result) {
                    console.log('save action is fired. -- VALID' + '--' + self.get('maxPrice'));
                } else {
                    console.log('save action is fired. -- INVALID');
                }
             });
         }
     }

});
```

Additionally when you're using the RSVP promise, you need to actually call `resolve`/`reject` for the promise to ever resolve or reject.  Here's a quick video on how to use RSVP promises: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WXgm4_V85E

Comment: hi Kingpin2k thanks a lot for the answer, it really seems the solution I am looking for, just one little thing, in line "this.checkValid(url).then(result) {" I got this error "Line 30: Unexpected token {" When I changed it to "this.isValidSearch(url).then(function(valid) {" the last error disappeared in logs but when I click the button it gives me another in console raised by the same line "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" .. Any idea?

Comment: hah, sorry, I totally missed the func definition.  Which line is it giving the undefined is not a function?

Comment: I see no worries ... The error actually is in the same line "this.checkValid(url).then(function(result) {"

Comment: I accept your question Kingpin2k because actually it saved my issue, but I still have this little error if somebody would give a hint.

Comment: Can you update the question with the current code you're using?

Comment: Thanks Kingpin2k, my colleague of work solved it by adding a RSVP promise when calling the ajax request, you mentioned it in your post, just thought it is not necessary in this case. Kind regards